# Circular dependency with reverse_delete_rule in Mongoengine

Tags: python, mongoengine, circular-dependency

I have the following mutually dependent models:

```
from mongoengine import *

class DocumentA(Document):
    docB = ReferenceField('DocumentB', reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)

class DocumentB(Document):
    docA = ReferenceField('DocumentA', reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
```

And I get the following error:

```
mongoengine.errors.NotRegistered: `DocumentB` has not been registered in the document registry.
            Importing the document class automatically registers it, has it
            been imported?
```

This error disappear if I remove the first `reverse_delete_rule`:

```
from mongoengine import *

class DocumentA(Document):
    docB = ReferenceField('DocumentB')

class DocumentB(Document):
    docA = ReferenceField('DocumentA', reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
```

Works fine.

Is there a way to keep the `reverse_delete_rule`?

Answer (score 1):

From [`MongoEngine` ReferenceField documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.ReferenceField) :

> Alternative syntax for registering delete rules (useful when
>   implementing bi-directional delete rules)
>
> ```
> class Bar(Document):
>     content = StringField()
>     foo = ReferenceField('Foo')
>
> Foo.register_delete_rule(Bar, 'foo', NULLIFY)
> ```

So your code becomes:

```
from mongoengine import *

class DocumentA(Document):
    docB = ReferenceField('DocumentB')

class DocumentB(Document):
    docA = ReferenceField('DocumentA', reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)

DocumentB.register_delete_rule(DocumentA, 'docB', CASCADE)
```